# JMeter scripts stop working, leaking memory, OutOfSpace Java

Tags: java, jmeter

After last Thursday (can be linked to Windows OS (10 v 1803, OS Build 17134.165) updates) all my JMeter scripts stopped work. I first noticed when all scripts that run in Non GUI mode failed with 
    `Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. See log file for details`.
I started to test with GUI mode and the log shows these:

```
WARN c.h.c.r.e.LoggingCSSParseErrorHandler: Browser compliant mode skipped CSS from [1:24125] starting at token 'data' until [1:24143] to token ';' (based on com.helger.css.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: ":" ":"
    at line 1, column 24129.

   Was expecting one of:
    ")"    "+"     "-"     "/"     "="     "["     "and"    "expression("   "from"     "inherit"     "not"     "only"     "or"     "to"     <ANGLE_DEG>    <ANGLE_GRAD>    <ANGLE_RAD>    <ANGLE_TURN>     <CH>    <COMMA>    <DPCM>    <DPI>     <DPPX>     <EM>    <EX>    <FR>    <FREQ_HZ>    <FREQ_KHZ>    <FUNCTION>    <FUNCTION_CALC>    <HASH>    <IDENT>    <LENGTH_CM>    <LENGTH_IN>
    <LENGTH_MM>    <LENGTH_PC>    <LENGTH_PT>    <LENGTH_Q>    <NUMBER>
    <PERCENTAGE>
    <PX>    <REM>    <S>    <STRING1>    <STRING2>    <TIME_MS>    <TIME_S>    <URANGE>    <URL>    <VH>    <VMAX>    <VMIN>    <VW>)
```

I see it on three machines: my local desktop, automation VM on perimeter, and at AWS. 
I have:

```
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

I also set:

```
css.parser.ignore_all_css_errors=true
```

I also tested that it happens with JMter 4.0 and 3.3. Java 1.8.0_152

Comment: What happens when you increase memory available to your process?

Comment: The same behavior. That is why I wrote that I set HEAP. It was at 512m

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First check:

- You're not running in GUI mode
- You're following best-practices:

  - https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
  - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

But if issue persists, add to command line:

> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=

Then share  using some sharing solution the generated hprof, and if possible your test plan.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It looks as there are several. In my jmx plan I was loading html pages. (We have a Single Web App architecture). Now after dev changed index.html I needed to disable html pages otherwise it blows.

My Test Plans (jmx) started to fail after dev changed index.html. It works correctly from UI perspective and from Selenium scripts. The change looks minor. They moved **base** tag from outside to inside **script** tag.

Before:

```
<base href="/ui/">
<script>
    //var HOST = 'http://localhost/';
    //var HOST = 'https://ooo.credifi.com/core/';
    var HOST = 'https://oo2.credifi.com/core/';
    var BASE = '/ui';
</script>
```

After:

```
  <script>
    var isLocalhost = document.location.hostname == 'localhost';
    var BASE = isLocalhost ? '' : '/ui';
    var HREF = isLocalhost ? '' : 'ui/';
    document.write('<base href="/' + HREF + '" />');
  </script>
```